# Can I use ssl:// and https:// in an URL interchangeably?

Tags: php, http, url, post, request

I have to write some PHP code to make a post request to an external server and got two different examples from the server owners, one using "ssl://" and the other "https://" in the URL.

Can they be used interchangeably? Where would this be documented? Thank you!

EDIT to include PHP code (not sure why I can't format the code properly, if someone can help with explaining how to incorporate the initial comment in the code block):

```
// make a http post request to an external server
function httpPost($host, $usepath, $postdata = "") {

    $fp = fsockopen($host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 60);
    if( !$fp ) {
        print "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
    }
    else {
        fwrite( $fp, "POST $usepath HTTP/1.0\n");
        $strlength = strlen( $postdata );
        fwrite( $fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n" );
        fwrite( $fp, "Content-length: ".$strlength."\n\n" );
        fwrite( $fp, $postdata."\n\n" );

        $output = "";

        while( !feof( $fp ) ) {
            $output .= fgets( $fp, 1024);
        }

        fclose( $fp);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I could edit your question and format it for you, but since you seem new to SO, you might as well try yourself: select the whole region of code when you edit, then click on the `{}` icon. This should insert 4 spaces in front of every selected line (and trigger the code formatting).

Comment: @Bruno - Indeed, that is what I wanted, to get how to do it myself. It looks much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssl://` URLs are quite specific to PHP. It's the way PHP provides a way to use a direct SSL/TLS connection when using its `fsocketopen` function. See [*List of Supported Socket Transports* in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php).

`ssl://` will give you an SSL/TLS connection without any application protocol on top of it: it will be up to your application to implement whichever protocol you require for the communication.

In contrast, `https://` will implement the HTTP protocol over this SSL/TLS connection.

Note that the [default settings for `ssl://` and `tls://` are rather poor in terms of security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php). In particular, the default value for `verify_peer` is false, which would make the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: Following your edit, your code is indeed implementing HTTP manually on top of this SSL/TLS connection for this request. Whether this is really required is questionable. I've not done this in PHP for a while, but I would assume you can send a POST request via HTTPS using other PHP functions directly, without re-inventing the wheel yourself.

Comment: I am working on a legacy website. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is HTTP protocol encrypted with SSL. A POST request is defined in the HTTP protocol, therefore you should use `https://` for that.

Looking at IANA's [list of URI schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), I did not see `ssl://`, therefore I would suggest against using it in any situation.

Comment: The thing is I was advised to use "ssl://" by the tech support of the server I need to connect to. Hope someone can explain why this should or not be avoided.

Comment: @user2237601 — Maybe it has some special meaning in the function you are using, but you haven't told us what that is so we can only talk about the general case.

Comment: @Quentin - I think it would be interesting to find out the general case answer, can we replace "ssl://" with "https://" ? I will edit my question to include the code as well though as I mentioned I was offered two different instructions by the server owners, which would suggest they consider the two versions identical.

Comment: The general case is, as mentioned in the answer, "No".